General term of the sequence defined recursively by $a_{n+1}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}a_ka_{n-k}.$
Let the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\ge 0} $ defined by $a_0=1, a_{n+1}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}a_ka_{n-k}.$
We are asked to find the general term $a_n$, and to show that this sequence is unique.
My approach:
I'm not sure this will help with finding the general term of the sequence, but I think that the following steps are the main ideas behind the solution. We can introduce the following function defined by $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^n$ and then try to form a second degree equation using the Cauchy product of two convergent series where f(x) is a solution of the equation. Thanks in advance.

You can try to make a conjecture and to prove it by induction or, letting
$$ f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{a_n}{n!}x^n $$
note that $f^2=-f'$ so this way you can find $f(x)$ and then $a_n$.

@Tuvasbien I don't think you want that $-$ sign.

@J.G. Yeah you're right, a shame I can't edit my comment.

Why not try to calculate the first few terms:
$$\begin{align}
a_1 &= a_0 a_0 = 1 \\
a_2 &= a_0 a_1 + a_1 a_0 = 1 + 1 = 2 \\
a_3 &= a_0 a_2 + 2 a_1 a_1 + a_2 a_0 = 2 + 2 + 2 = 6 \\
a_4 &= a_0 a_3 + 3 a_1 a_2 + 3 a_2 a_1 + a_3 a_0 = 6 + 6 + 6 + 6 = 24 \\
a_5 &= a_0 a_4 + 4 a_1 a_3 + 6 a_2 a_2 + 4 a_3 a_1 + a_4 a_0 = 24 + 24 + 24 + 24 + 24 = 120
\end{align}$$
and by now, you should be able to spot the pattern.  So the question becomes, how would you go about proving it?  What kind of strategies come to mind?

To add to this, you may find pleasure in an induction argument to prove a much more simple recursive formula (which - thanks to @heropup's calculation - strikes visually), from which you can try to cook up an explicit formula.

Putting the suggested values into the recurrence makes a lot of the term cancel out which makes the inductive proof somewhat trivial.
